# Is it possible to have embedded sending and signing for bulk?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

For example, let's say I'm building a bulk send workflow with the DocuSign API so that it'll be integrated into a school's website. Teachers want to be able to send out permission slips and such to all the parents through their school portal. There is currently a system already in place that makes use of embedded sending an embedded signing, but of course this only works for single envelopes. Is it possible to have a similar system for bulk?

Answer (score 0):

The `bulkSendingCopyRecipient` object, defined in the [BulkSend:createBulkSendList](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/BulkEnvelopes/BulkSend/createBulkSendList#definitions) method page does indeed allow you to set the `clientUserId` for each bulk send recipient.

So you should be able to create a bulk send of envelopes that include recipients who will use an embedded signing ceremony.

Try it out and let us know if it works! (I haven't tried this myself.)